# Newly created component in Angular are missing header and footer

Tags: angular

I'm not really sure how angular works but here's my folder structure first.
[image]

So i created a dashboard-agent folder containing new  components but they're just naked without  any header and  footer.

[image]

In the  second picture, the dashboard folder inside the  admin  folder was newly  created too  but somehow  that one  has everything. Header and footer. I cannot recreate  the dashboard agent in  the admin folder  because they  use  the different header  and footer.

Comment: The best place to start is on https://angular.io/docs.  You can also find some tutorials on Pluralsight.com, but you have to pay for a membership every month.  Another place is Udemy.com.  But anyway, start on the getting started from the Angular website.

Comment: Here's the getting started page:  https://angular.io/start.  Please make sure that you also do the tutorial in order for you to practice.

Comment: I didn't quite followed `dashboard-agent folder containing new components don't have header and footer`. When you create a new component using cli what it does?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara It generated a new html,css and ts file. I did the same with the  dashboard folder in admin. Perhaps the difference lies in the  module? Because i imported the dashboard  component in the admin module and admin routes.ts  while the  dashboard agent was imported in app.module  and app-routing

Comment: @Auguste alright  thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular cli to do it. A simple command can do the work:

```
ng g c nameComponent --module=modulename
```

It doesn't matter where you are in the app folder, generally, when you create a component the cli adds it to the nearest module, but being at root you can also add the component in specific module using above command.